# Как запретить доступ к elasticsearch из вне, я использую php sdk

Tags: php, linux, elasticsearch

Подскажите как закрыть удаленный доступ к elasticsearch ? Я использую docker и php sdk для работы с эластиком

```
  elasticsearch:
image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
container_name: es
environment:
  - node.name=es
  - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
  - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es
  - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
  - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
ulimits:
  memlock:
    soft: -1
    hard: -1
volumes:
  - ./storage/docker/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
ports:
  - 9201:9200
restart: always
```

Comment: по умолчанию доступа извне к выполняющемуся внутри docker-контейнера процессу нет. следовательно, раз доступ есть, вы его явно разрешили. каким именно образом — знаете только вы.

Comment: Может изза проброса портов такое происходит, можете глянуть конфиг ?